# Please make me understand the reason behind why numpy.isfinite function is used in the below code?

Tags: python, numpy

** I have a CSV file, containing Oympics data for summers as well as winters for all the countries, the problem statement is -> Which country has the biggest difference between their summer gold medal counts and winter gold medal counts relative to their total gold medal count?

Only include countries that have won at least 1 gold in both summer and winter. **

```
import numpy as np
    def answer_three():
        copy_df = df.copy()
        copy_df = copy_df.where(df['Gold'] > 0)
        copy_df = copy_df.where(df['Gold.1'] > 0)
        copy_df['Diff'] = copy_df['Gold'] - copy_df['Gold.1']
        copy_df['Gold_Ratio'] = copy_df['Diff'] / (copy_df['Gold'] + copy_df['Gold.1'])
        copy_df_final = copy_df[np.isfinite(copy_df['Gold_Ratio'])]
        max_ratio = max(copy_df_final['Gold_Ratio'])
    
        return (str(copy_df_final[copy_df_final['Gold_Ratio'] == max_ratio].index[0]))
    answer_three()
```

Comment: Yes, right i mean, isinfinite. my bad

Comment: Show us *exactly* what you don't understand from when you traced the intermediate expressions in this code. "Explain this code block to me" is out of scope for Stack Overflow: deconstruct the compound expressions and tell us what you don't understand about one or two of those operations.

Comment: In particular, what happens with the data case when you do *not* filter with `isfinite`?  Do you know what the function does?  What problems would you have the the division on the previous line?

Comment: if i eliminate the isfinite line of code and make appropriate changes - the error i am getting is - "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" . to answer your 2nd question, the function extracts data from two columns of a dataframe, makes a copy df then substract 1 column(Gold) with other (Gold.1) and the result is then divided by addition of these two columns then i am using the result of division to extract the index in order to find the country name(index) in this case. my question is as far as i know python and numpy, i would not need isfinite in this case to find the index value.

Comment: What data values cause problems?  How does `isfinite` work around those problems?

Answer (score 0):

I Think i might got the solution in the third and fourth line of code `copy_df = copy_df.where(df['Gold'] > 0)` and `copy_df = copy_df.where(df['Gold.1'] > 0)` i am only allowing values greater than '0' so, apparently other rows for each columns where values are not >0 are filled with NaN values, and hence the use of isfinite. Please correct me, if my interpretation is wrong.